# Enable/disable button for the dates in a specific range

Tags: javascript

I can enable the/disable the button for particular date but I want to enable the button for a particular range of date like from 20th september to 25th september. Please help in this.
I can get date using:

```
var st = srvTime(st);
var serverdate = new Date();
var dd=serverdate.getDate();
var mm=serverdate.getMonth()+1;
var day=serverdate.getDay();
var hours = serverdate.getHours();
var minute = serverdate.getMinutes();
```

and I can enable/disable like this.

```
if(mm==9 && dd==17)
{
document.getElementById('visibletalk').className = 'btnsubmit';
document.getElementById('talknow').style.display='block';
document.getElementById('talksubmit').style.display='none';
if((hours >= 9)&&(hours <=19))
{
    if((hours==19)&&(minute>00) || (hours==9)&&(minute<30))
    {
        $("#talknow").hide();
        $("#talksubmit").show();
    }

    else
    {
        $("#talksubmit").hide();
        $("#talknow").show();
    }
}
else
{
    $("#talknow").hide();
    $("#talksubmit").show();
}
}
```

How to do this same for 20th september to 25th september

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare a range in the initial if query. Replace `if(mm==9 && dd==17)` by `if (mm == 9 && dd >=20 && <= 25))`.

Comment: used like this works `((mm == 9 && (dd <=23)) && (mm == 9 && (15 <= dd)))`

Comment: Yeah sorry, defnitly a mistake of mine (wrong language). Better version of your idea: `(mm == 9 && dd >= 20 && dd <= 25)`